# I have installed nemo file manager on ubuntu 22.10 and there is a bug with it

Tags: nautilus, nemo, 22.10

I have installed Nemo file manager on Ubuntu 22.10, so I noticed that when I switch the workspace, the desktop icons remain in sight. I know that what I just said is unclear but I am sure that the picture I have attached will make it really clear.
What the picture shows it does not happen with the nautilus file manager.
I hope you understand me and sorry for my English, I am Italian.[image: i]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. The questions in this site are answered by volunteer Ubuntu users just like you. For this reason bugs are off topic here. See [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) for how to report a bug.

Comment: Please accept the answer by clicking on the gray check ✔️ next to the answer and turn it green ✅. This will mark your problem as solved and help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nemo is not designed to work with desktop icons on Gnome Shell, and Gnome Shell actually is designed to work without desktop icons. Both just do their job independently, leading to the artifact you see when switching workspaces. Ignore the artifact - it does not in any way affect the use of your computer. Alternatively, turn of animations (Settings - Accessibility). There is an extension that can [turn off animations for switching workspaces](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1328/disable-workspace-switch-animation/) only, but it has not yet been updated for 22.10

Comment: Understood. Thanks for answering me. Now I have removed the desktop icons and disabled the animations so that I don't see the artifact that Nemo file manager makes on Gnome. hoping they will solve a little thing like this as soon as possible because I love Nemo file manager on ubuntu, it make use almost perfect rather than Nautilus, for me.

Comment: No, they won't. Gnome Shell is intended to get rid of desktop icons. A dedicated extension brings these back in, and accounts for this artefact. Nemo developpers will not be inclined to accomodate for this (actually only aesthetical) issue on Gnome Shell. If you remove desktop icons, there is no need to disable animations?